# Python count two arrays of strings and integers

Tags: python-3.x, counter

I have two arrays X and Y, X holds a title of a product that repeats, Y holds integer amounts of how many of X was sold.

I used Counter to count the number of occurrences for each element in X, but it does not take into account Y.

```
from collections import Counter
x = ['a','a','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','d','e','e']
y = [1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 1, 8, 1]

countX = Counter(x)
```

Comment: How *would* it? It doesn't get passed y at all.

Comment: I know just showing what I tried, wouldn't be here if I had the question solved

Answer (score 0):

Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e']
y = [1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 1, 8, 1]    

output = defaultdict(int)

for prod, count in zip(x, y):
    output[prod] += count

print(output)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 6, 'd': 8, 'e': 9})
```

Comment: Not sure but my upvote brought it to a 0, but thank you so much for the help!